# Python s.recv() returns empty string

Tags: python, sockets, server

I've got a simple client and server I found on an online tutorial

---

```
#server.py        

import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = 'localhost' # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port  
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
   c.close()                # Close the connection
```

---

```
#client           # This is client.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = 'localhost' 
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

---

When I run my c`lient.py` all it does is print an empty string when it should print ('Thank you for connecting'). When I connect localhost 12345 from telnet it sends the message  fine so I don't know why my client isn't receiving the message

Any thoughts. I'm very new to socket programming and would love to find a solution so I can move on.

Comment: I can't reproduce your situation.  The code works as expected for me.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.7.14

Comment: I'm assuming the tutorial was using 2 and not 3 because the print isn't a function call. What version are you using?

Comment: I can't produce the said behavior with Python 2.7.13 on Linux. By the way - your client does not _Close the socket when done_ due to missing `()`.

Answer (score 0):

While running your script as is, I got this error:

```
Waiting connections ...
Got connection from ('127.0.0.1', 63875)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serv.py", line 14, in <module>
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Few things here:

- Ensure you're sending `bytes` instead of `str`. you could do this by replacing line 14 with:

  ```
  c.send(b'Thank you for connecting')
  ```
- Also, it's always useful to declare your sockets `s` like this:

  ```
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
  ```

Further read:

- Py2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html
- Py3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

Hope it works! :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply unfortunately it's the same issue as before. I'm just getting an empty string back. Also I've never recieved the error message you got. I'm beginning to think this issue has nothing to do with the code.